# Objective C to Swift Error

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm using some objective c stuff within my Swift project. I created a bridging header.

I'm receiving an error on this line in one of the files:

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, self.viewSize.width, 216);
```

> member reference base type Size (aka long) is not a structure or union

If I replace it with something like 100 it works. What would be a recommended replacement for self.viewSize.width?

Thanks!

Comment: `CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(...)` is (Objective-)C syntax. How is the problem related to Swift?

Comment: Maybe xcode6 is taking issue to it? Not too sure. Any thoughts why it would throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out self.viewSize was of type 'Size' when it should've been of type CGSize.